# CiviCRM 4.6.27 on Drupal 7 says it can't write version-info-cache.json but it can

Tags: permissions, filesystem

CiviCRM is giving me the following error:

```
Unable to write file:
/var/www/html/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/version-info-cache.json
```

The problem is that CiviCRM can write that file, and if I delete that file, CiviCRM will re-create that file.

CiviCRM creates the file with the apache user as the owner and group and with 644 permissions. Does anyone know of a fix or workaround for this?

I started receiving this error after upgrading to the latest version of 4.6 (from an earlier 4.6 version.)